# jQuery on('submit') not working with form created through document.createElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone explain why `$('body').on('submit')` is not working for dynamically created form? The event is bind after the form has been created and appended to `body` so I was expecting that `form_handler` should kick in but it didn't.

```
form_handler = function(){
    alert('ok');
}

function create_form(){
    var f = document.createElement('form');
    f.method = 'POST';
    f.action = '/echo/html/';
    f.className = 'test_form';
    document.body.appendChild(f);
    return f;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var form = create_form();
    $('body').on('submit', 'form.test_form', form_handler);
    form.submit();
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7seedj0j/). Forgive me if I am making an obvious mistake.

**UPDATE**

I can not use `jQuery submit` method as suggested by `@Vohuman`. The problem is that the third party library is creating a dynamic form and submitting it. And I am using jQuery to catch that.

Comment: @Script47 does it matter?

Answer (score 2):

The `HTMLFormElement.submit` method bypasses jQuery `submit` listener. You can wrap the element with jQuery and use the jQuery `submit` method.

```
$(form).submit();
```

Comment: The problem is that the third party library is creating a dynamic form and submitting it. And I am using jQuery to catch that. I can't change that. I should have mentioned that in actual question sorry.

Comment: One dirty option is overriding the `HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit` method. If modifying the third party library's source code was an option I'd do that instead.